# MeteorJS application not working once deployed on MeteorJS cloud

Tags: meteor

I deployed my MeteorJS web application (http://caloriecounter.meteor.com/) but for some reason it is not working. User should be able to sign in/sign up and be able to add meals and the meals should be displayed under the date in a table once the meals are added.

It is working locally but I'm not sure why its not working once I deployed it. I've been attempting to look at possible errors and I've looked at the console under developer tools but there seems to be nothing coming up there either.

So I'm a little lost on what is exactly going on. Please advise.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I just think of different data on server vs. your local instance. Maybe your code require certain data to be available.

My suggestion:

- Reset your local instance (note: your local database will be cleaned!): `$ meteor reset`
- or just create a local copy with empty database